# mod_wsgi, wsgi daemon visible behind _both_ http and https

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi, web2py

I have apache vhost configured with SSL and mod_wsgi its working fine:

< VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443 >

```
#[...]
SSLEngine on 
#[...]
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/maciek/workspace/imid2py/wsgihandler.py
WSGIDaemonProcess web2py user=maciek group=www-data \ 
              home=/home/maciek/workspace/imid2py/  \
              processes=10 maximum-requests=500
```

< Location "/" >

```
   #[...]
   WSGIProcessGroup web2py
```

< /Location >

< /VirtualHost >

However, I need to allow connections to specific url over http without ssl.
So basically I want _the_same_ WSGI daemon to be visible on two virtual hosts: one with ssl, one without. I want this to be same daemon, because I use some common variables in memory. A way around is possible (ex, storing them in db) but painstaking.

< VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>

```
    <Location "/welcome/default/handleRequest">
            WSGIProcessGroup web2py  #I want this to be the same daemon as above
    </Location>
```

< /VirtualHost >

How can I configure wsgi/apache to do that? Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is covered by web2py documentation in web2py book. Go read the sections of that book. See links at:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithWeb2Py

Comment: That's a very useful link, I didn't know it before. Your blog posts are very insightful and helpful. This one specifically solves my problem:
http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/08/more-on-those-problems-with-example.html

Thanks!

Comment: I have one more question:
 "ports 80 and 443 are generally paired together for a site,  mod_wsgi makes an exception in this case and will actually assign requests for the WSGI application through either port to run in the same sub interpreter"  -- Can I achieve this effect for different pair of ports? (ex. 5443 and 8080)?

Comment: You can control which sub interpreters requests are run in using the WSGIApplicationGroup directive. See 'http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIApplicationGroup'.